# GATE annotation counting

Tags: gate

I am trying to figure out a way of counting some annotations in GATE e.g. if I have some annotations occurring multiple times in a text document and if I want to count it, is there some sort of plugin that can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All that is necessary is just to get these annotations and then call a `.size()` method. `AnnotationSet` in GATE extends Java collection classes.

```
AnnotationSet annotationSet = gateDocument.getAnnotations().get("ABC");
int size=annotationSet.size();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a groovy script. The code is from [here](http://gate.ac.uk/wiki/groovy-recipes/):

```
sum = 0
docs.findAll{ // get all documents currently loaded
  def filteredAnnots = it.getAnnotations("Filtered")
  num = filteredAnnots["Anatomy"].size()
  sum += num
  println it.name + " " + num // or print to a file here
}
println "total:" + " " + sum
```

You can also easily put this code in a groovy plugin (PR) and run it as part of the pipeline, described [here](http://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch7.html#x11-1950007.17.2).